# How to append the 1st row of separate columns to a list of lists

Tags: python, list, append

How can I append the first row from every column into a list of lists? I have attempted this through the following code but can't seem to get it working.

```
data = [[],[],[]]

xy = ([1,2,3,4,5,9], [7,4,9,2,3,8], [1,2,3,4,5,9], [7,4,9,2,3,8])

data[0].append(xy(list(map(float,row[1:4][::2])))

Expected output:
[1,7,1,7]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: And what is `row`?

Comment: Sorry @DyZ. I adjusted the question. It was meant to read first row, not first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple comprehension of the first items from each sub-list (whether you call them columns or rows) will work:

```
xy = ([1,2,3,4,5,9], [7,4,9,2,3,8], [1,2,3,4,5,9], [7,4,9,2,3,8])

[row[0] for row in xy]
# [1, 7, 1, 7]
```